# Como imprimir Tiquete de Venta en impresora POS desde Java

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Actualmente tengo un inconveniente, estoy haciendo una aplicación en Java SE para un local comercial. El local cuenta con una impresora EPSON de la serie TM (También conocida como impresora térmica o POS).

El fabricante no ofrece mucha información y realmente lo que logro encontrar en Internet no es muy claro para mi, necesito saber, como logro imprimir un tiquete de venta similar a lo siguiente, implementando algún método en Java y de antemano muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego lo siguiente para mostrar los resultados en base a una sugerencia dada sobre la siguiente documentación: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html

Cuando realizo la impresion del ticket, los valores salen desordenados ademas de que cuando la descripcion es demasiado larga, se pierden los valores del precio del producto. Cuando deberia realizarse alguna especie de salto de linea. Adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Imprimir en java es como dibujar en un canvas, sugiero que leas un poco del tema en https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html

Comment: Hola @JonnathanQ , ya vi esa documentación, pero esta no funciona como esperaba o como requiero exactamente, los valores salen todos desalineados, e incluso cuando la descripción del item es muy larga, el valor del costo que debería ir al lado de esa descripción, se sale o queda incompleto en la impresión. Voy a editar mi pregunta para mostrar el resultado de esta prueba en base a su recomendación.

Comment: Si, lamentablemente utilizar esta funcionalidad de impresión no es tan fácil, se convierte en un tema de prueba y error, sobre todo si analizas de acuerdo a la imagen que colocaste una linea solo puede contener 37 caracteres, así que tendrías que ajustar el contenido para que sea visible en solo 37 caracteres, podrias tal vez utilizar una letra mas pequeña y asi ganar mas caracteres. Por eso es muy comun en sistemas pos ver que las descripciones no son tan largas, o son abreviadas.

Comment: Quizás esto te sea de utilidad http://kb.certek.com/article/AA-00348/0/Print-Logo-on-Receipt-Using-Epson-TM-T20-Printer.html

Comment: Tengo una idea, y es la de modificar la distribución de la data que quiero imprimir, voy a probar ya que es como tu dices, al parecer es un tema de prueba y error. Igual sigo atento en caso de que se den cuenta de alguna solución o alternativa

Comment: Tendrás algún ejemplo? en una mini aplicación sencilla de java para saber como utilizarlo?
ando pasando por los mismos problemas que tuviste y ya tengo días así :(

Comment: @enrique91 si gustas enviame un correo a ignitedevsoft@gmail.com, ya que tengo una app, pero el proyecto lo tengo en un repositorio privado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quería decir que ya logre realizar el ticket, tal cual como lo mostré en la pregunta. Tuve que investigar bastante. Encontré una librería o API llamada Util, la cual permite indicar el tamaño de papel, también desde que columna a que columna del documento quieres escribir y también trae un método que permite alinear textos a la derecha o izquierda desde donde donde debería finalizar o iniciar a escribir en el archivo.

Adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto un código de ejemplo, aunque quizás pueda generar duda, ademas que en si requiere el uso del JAR que menciono anteriormente, igualmente dejo un correo de contacto si se requiere algún tipo de aclaración o apoyo.

Correo: ignitedevsoft@gmail.com

```
import br.com.adilson.util.Extenso;
import br.com.adilson.util.PrinterMatrix;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

void imprimirTicket(JTable jtbl_venta, String subTotal, String total, String dineroR, String devolucion){
try {

    PrinterMatrix printer = new PrinterMatrix();
    Extenso e = new Extenso();

    e.setNumber(20.30);
    //Definir el tamanho del papel para la impresion de dinamico y 32 columnas
    int filas = jtbl_venta.getRowCount();
    int tamaño = filas+40;
    printer.setOutSize(tamaño, 80);

    //Imprimir = 1ra linea de la columa de 1 a 32
    printer.printTextWrap(0, 1, 5, 80, "===================================================================");
    printer.printTextWrap(1, 1, 35, 80, "CARNIVOROS"); //Nombre establecimiento
    printer.printTextWrap(3, 1, 31, 80, "Barrio Bellavista"); //Barrio
    printer.printTextWrap(4, 1, 37, 80, "Clle 47"); //Direccion
    printer.printTextWrap(5, 1, 38, 80, "12345"); //Codigo Postal
    printer.printTextWrap(6, 1, 10, 41, "Fecha"); //Aqui va la fecha de recibo
    printer.printTextWrap(6, 1, 38, 80, "Hora"); //Aqui va la hora de recibo
    printer.printTextWrap(7, 1, 3, 80, "Numero"); //Numero del recibo - FACTURA O PEDIDO
    printer.printTextWrap(8, 1, 3, 80, "Atiende"); //Nombre Cajero
    printer.printTextWrap(9, 1, 3, 80, "Cliente");//Nombre del Cliente
    printer.printTextWrap(10,1, 5, 80, "——————————–——————————–——————————–——————————–——–———–——–—–———–——–———");
    printer.printTextWrap(11,1, 7, 80, "ID   DESCRIPCION                        CANT           PRECIO");
    printer.printTextWrap(12,1, 0, 80, " ");

    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
        int p = 13+i; //Fila

        printer.printTextWrap(p , 1, 7, 19 , jtbl_venta.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
        printer.printTextWrap(p , 1, 12, 42 , jtbl_venta.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
        printer.printTextWrap(p , 1, 47, 49, jtbl_venta.getValueAt(i,2).toString());

        String pre= printer.alinharADireita(10, jtbl_venta.getValueAt(i,3).toString());
        printer.printTextWrap(p , 1, 57, 80, pre);

        //String inp= printer.alinharADireita(7,punto_Venta.jtbl_venta.getValueAt(i,6).toString());
        //printer.printTextWrap(p , 1, 25, 32, inp);
    }
    DecimalFormat formateador = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

    String sub= printer.alinharADireita(10, subTotal);
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+17, 1, 5, 80, "Subtotal: ");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+17, 1, 20, 80, "$"+sub);

    String tot= printer.alinharADireita(10, total);
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+18, 1, 5, 80, "Total a pagar: ");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+18, 1, 20, 80, "$"+tot);

    String efe= printer.alinharADireita(10,dineroR);
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+19, 1, 5, 80, "Efectivo : ");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+19, 1, 20, 80, "$"+efe);

    String cam= printer.alinharADireita(10,devolucion);
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+20, 1, 5, 80, "Cambio : ");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+20, 1, 20, 80, "$"+ cam);

    printer.printTextWrap(filas+21, 1, 5, 80, "——————————–——————————–——————————–——————————–——–———–——–—–———–——–———");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+22, 1, 26,80, "!Gracias por su preferencia!");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+23, 1, 30, 80, "WorkIt App - v1.0.0");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+24, 1, 31, 80, "Software a Medida");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+25, 1, 25, 80, "Contacto: workitapp@gmail.com");
    printer.printTextWrap(filas+26, 1, 5,80, "===================================================================");


    ///CREAR ARCHIVO EN CARPETA DEL PROYECTO PARA PEDIDOS
    printer.toFile("C:\\tmp\\impresion.txt");
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\tmp\\impresion.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar");
    }
    if (inputStream == null) {
        return;
    }

    DocFlavor docFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc document = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, docFormat, null);
    PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    if (defaultPrintService != null) {
        DocPrintJob printJob = defaultPrintService.createPrintJob();
        try {
            printJob.print(document, attributeSet);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("No existen impresoras instaladas");
    }

    inputStream.close();
    //imprimirFin(subTotal, total, dineroR, devolucion); //ESTE METODO NO SE UTILIZARA

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al imprimir "+e);
    }
```

}

Recuerden que la clase PrinterMatrix y Extenso requieren de importar el JAR que ya les había mencionado.

Espero que pueda servir a alguien.